# Webpack: how to override module ids?

Tags: webpack, versioning

The problem:
We are splitting the code of SPA into multiple bundles. Each bundle has its own version. So in prod we want to use different versions of bundles, based on user's config. Therefore we need to ensure that module ids won't change between versions (for the same module).

One of possible solutions is to define `recordsPath` in config and store records' file under VC. But the file always grows when we update our libs.

Another option is to override how webpack generates module ids in `Compilation.prototype.applyModuleIds` (e.g. we can use relative path to module as module id).

Is this safe to do or we just missed something and there is some webpack feature or plugin to handle our problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears perfectly safe to do this in Webpack 1.9.x. YMMV with webpack 2, but I would not expect so due to the simple nature of the method.

So long as you satisfy the condition that the same module will always be given the same ID then webpack will function as normal. I ended up using the following implementation:

```
var md5 = require('md5');

module.exports = function handleWebpackModuleSymlinks(Compilation) {
  Compilation.prototype.applyModuleIds = function() {
    this.modules.forEach(function(module) {
      if (module.id === null) {
        module.id = md5(module.userRequest);
      }
    }, this);
  };
}
```

This will create module hashes based off the resolved absolute path to each file, which is behaviour that should work out of the box but I needed to implement myself due to use of symlinked `node_modules` during development throwing off its default path comparison logic. You could likely use regexes to replace the version component of your resource paths prior to hashing in order to achieve the intended effect.